# Prevent class property from being serialized

Tags: c#, xml

I added attribute serializable to class but, due to this, class property is getting serialized.

I used `[XmlIgnore]` to all property but still it is serializing the property

```
[Serializable]
public class Document
{

    [DataMember]
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string FileURL { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string FileSize { get; set; }       

}
```

It's serialized like below tag-

```
<a:_x003C_DocumentDetails_x003E_k__BackingField>
  <a:Document>                  
    <a:_x003C_FileType_x003E_k__BackingField>PDF</a:_x003C_FileType_x003E_k__BackingField>
    <a:_x003C_FileURL_x003E_k__BackingField>C:/log/Test.pdf</a:_x003C_FileURL_x003E_k__BackingField>                    
  </a:Document>
</a:_x003C_DocumentDetails_x003E_k__BackingField>
```

Comment: There are several serialisation techniques (WCF, XMLSerializer).  Could you post the code you are using to serialize your code (and/or technique) and then we can give you advice on what attribute to use. I'm thinking WCF but it won't serialise anything that isn't a data member.

Comment: I m doing coding in WCF. for serialization i added only this attributre [Serializable] , and it is serializing and giving the data. 

didn't wrote any extra code for serializing.

Comment: Making property private will prevent from getting serialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `[JsonIgnore]` or `[IgnoreDataMember]` attribute, that will help you.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using [the `[Serializable]` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples), you need to use the `[NonSerialized]` attribute on any members (public or private) that you don't want serialised.

`[DataMember]` is used when the class is marked with the `[DataContract]` attribute and `[XmlIgnore]` is used when you are explicitly using the XmlSerialiser on a class.

```
[Serializable]
public class Document {
  [NonSerialized]
  public string FileURL { get; set; }

  [NonSerialized]
  public string FileSize { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using WCF with an "out of the box" configuration, you're probably using the `DataContractSerializer` to serialize messages, not the `XmlSerializer`.

In order to have members of your contract class not be serialized, you decorate them with the [`IgnoredDataMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[Serializable]
public class Document
{
    [DataMember]
    public string FileURL { get; set; }

    [IgnoredDataMember]
    public string FileSize { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried IgnoreDataMemberAttribute as per the docs?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute.aspx